# Can I express this sum of a piecewise function as an integral?

Tags: calculus, piecewise-continuity

I've become a bit stuck on a problem I'm working on. I have a sum of a piecewise function defined as follows:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N}
\begin{cases}
\delta & x\leq g(n\delta) \\
\delta \frac{g(n\delta)^3}{x^5} & x\geq g(n\delta)
\end{cases}
$$
Here, $g(n\delta)$ is a function and $\delta$ is a small, constant increment. Thus as $n$ gets large and $\delta
$ becomes infinitesimally small, the sum begins to look like an integral.

I feel like I should be able to write this as a collection of definite integrals, but I'm not sure where to begin, nor how to deal with the fact that the limits are variable.

Any clues on what I should do here?

Thanks,
Hugh

EDIT: I think the real issue I'm struggling with is how to handle a domain that varies with the summation index, e.g.:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{N} \left(Q \textrm{ for: } x \leq x_i\right)$$
$Q$ may be a constant, but the domain varies with $i$, and is therefore included in the summation.

Comment: Who is $\delta_y$? The Dirac's delta?

Comment: It's a small increment in y. Thanks for pointing this out - I'll edit the question.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it more, the real issue is that the domain is variable. In other words, is there a simpler way to write:
$f(x) = \sum_{n_0}^{N}\delta$    for $x \leq g(n\delta)$
?